# Getting Mongo results from how to get the Particular time data

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have this data in mongodb:

```
[
{
     _id:1,
    "CreateDate" : ISODate("2018-08-05T20:01:00.840Z")

},
{
    _id:2,
    "CreateDate" : ISODate("2018-08-05T21:53:51.840Z")

},
{
     _id:3,
    "CreateDate" : ISODate("2018-09-06T00:02:51.840Z")
 },
{
     _id:4,
    "CreateDate" : ISODate("2018-09-06T04:53:51.840Z")
 },


]
```

I am new to MongoDb and would appreciate some help with this query. I wrote the following aggregation pipeline.i wrote the query i have taken last 24 hours data but how could get the data from particular time with (00:01:00 to 05:00:00 and 20:00:00 to 23:59:00)any one please suggest me.

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
{$match: {createDate: {$gt: new Date(new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000*60*60*24))}}},
])
```

i got the last 24 hours data how to get (00:01:00 to 05:00:00 and 20:00:00 to 23:59:00)particular time data with by default everyday

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/hour/

Comment: I am littele bit confused please suggest with me.